# Handling "reset by peer" scenario with boost::asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I have a server method that waits for new incoming `TCP` connections, for each connection I'm creating two threads (detached) for handling various tasks.

```
    void MyClass::startServer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port) {

        tcp::acceptor TCPAcceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

        bool UARTToWiFiGatewayStarted = false;

        for (;;) {

            auto socket(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>(new tcp::socket(io_service)));

            /*!
             * Accept a new connected WiFi client.
             */
            TCPAcceptor.accept(*socket);

            socket->set_option( tcp::no_delay( true ) );

            MyClass::enableCommunicationSession();

            // start one worker thread.
            std::thread(WiFiToUARTWorkerSession, socket, this->LINport, this->LINbaud).detach();

            // only if this is the first connected client:
            if(false == UARTToWiFiGatewayStarted) {

                std::thread(UARTToWifiWorkerSession, socket, this->UARTport, this->UARTbaud).detach();

                UARTToWiFiGatewayStarted = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine for starting the communication, but the problem appears when the client disconnects and connects again (or at least tries to connect again).

When the current client disconnects, I stop the communication (by stopping the internal infinite loops from both functions, then they'll return).

```
    void Gateway::WiFiToUARTWorkerSession(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket, ...) {

        /*!
         * various code here...
         */

        try {
            while(true == MyClass::communicationSessionStatus) {

                /*!
                 * Buffer used for storing the UART-incoming data.
                 */
                unsigned char WiFiDataBuffer[max_incoming_wifi_data_length];

                boost::system::error_code error;

                /*!
                 * Read the WiFi-available data.
                 */
                size_t length = socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(WiFiDataBuffer), error);

                /*!
                 * Handle possible read errors.
                 */
                if (error == boost::asio::error::eof) {
                    break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
                }
                else if (error) {
                    // this will cause the infinite loops from the both worker functions to stop, and when they stop the functions will return.
                    MyClass::disableCommunicationSession();
                    sleep(1);
                    throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
                }

                uart->write(WiFiDataBuffer, length);
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception &exception) {
            std::cerr << "[APP::exception] Exception in thread: " << exception.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I expect that when I reconnect the communication should work again (the `MyClass::startServer(...)` will create and `detach` again two worker threads that will do the same things.

The problem is that when I connect the second time I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  write: Broken pipe
```

From what I found about this error it seems that the server (this application) sends something via `TCP` to a client that was disconnected.

What I'm doing wrong?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. A read of length 0 with no error is also an indication of eof. The `boost::asio::error::eof` error code is normally more useful when you're checking the result of a composed operation.
2. When this error condition is missed, the code as presented will call `write` on a socket which has now been shutdown. You have used the form of write which does not take a reference to an `error_code`. This form will throw if there is an error. There will be an error. The read has failed.

Comment: I'll fix that, but I don't think that this is the problem, since when the client disconnects the execution flow goes through the `else if (error)` path.

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Comment: I don't do this, that `uart->write(WiFiDataBuffer, length);` line writes the data on some `UART` socket, not the `boost::asio` one. The only I/O I do with the `boost::asio` socket is via the argument-passed `socket` object.

Comment: If "read of length 0 with no error is also an indication of eof", how would you detect the difference between a delay on the sending side and the end of the stream?

Comment: @sehe asio does not have any inherent timeouts. If you want a timeout you construct a deadline_timer and then `cancel()` the socket's async operations in its handler.

Comment: So, what did you mean when you said "read of length 0 with no error is also an indication of eof"? Did you mean "the end of available data _for now_ (± _n_ µs¹)"
? (¹ depending on circumstance)

Comment: @sehe no, just like the berkely read() call, it's a blocking call (unless non-blocking flag is set) which will return when either there is a data, or there is an error, or an end of stream (other end signalled shutdown). a return value of zero with no error indicates that the other end signalled shutdown, and there is no more data to read (i.e. same as EOF)

Comment: Ah, clear. I guess non-blocking is useless in the case of async IO? And that EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK would be returned. Thanks!